# How to send MobilePush data into a data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, mobilepush, mobilesdk, contactbuilder

So I have a client that has been sending MobilePush data using an SDK to "All Contacts" in Contact Builder from their Mobile App.

The question that I have is whether this same MobilePush data can be sent to a data extension using their existing SDK. Is this possible? If so, is there any documentation out there that shows how MobilePush data can be sent to a data extension using SDK.

Or can MobilePush data be sent to a data extension only using API?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The SDK has no ability to load a DE, you could use filtered list to segment audience based on these attributes